# GetFeature URL not UTF-8 which leads to an error

Tags: geoserver, error, getfeature, request

I'm cascading an external WFS to my own WMS and ran into this. The external WFS uses `å` in a property name. Which the GeoServer has no trouble reading into my layer and I can see the geometrics in a preview. When I click an element to load features it fails.

It returns this error:

```
"Failed to load attribute list, internal error is: org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSException: WFS returned an exception. 
Originating Request: GET_FEATURE[ handle: GeoTools 23.1(b44c873520665036e40f1f3d429178760cc808f6) WFS 1.1.0 DataStore @"Blanked" outputFormat: <text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1> method: GET onlineResource: <https://webkort.aarhuskommune.dk:443/wfs/spatialsuite/wfs?> final URL: <https://webkort.aarhuskommune.dk:443/wfs/spatialsuite/wfs?PROPERTYNAME=MI_STYLE%2CID%2CKommuneplanramme%2CLokalplan%2CVedtaget_LP%2CLP_u_udarb%2CSkole%2CStat%2CAreal_ha%2CKomm%2CPriv%2CFam_boliger%2CSm%EF%BF%BD_boliger%2CFB_2021_22%2CSB_2021_22%2CFB_2023_25%2CSB_2023_25%2CFB_2026_31%2CSB_2026_31%2CFB_Senere%2CSB_Senere%2CAlmene_Fam%2CAlmene_S%2CLokalsamfund%2CKategori_tal%2CKategori_tekst%2CKategori_til_kort%2CKat_til_kort_nr%2COprettet_af%2COprettet_dato%2CRettet_af%2CRettet_dato%2Cmi_prinx%2CBemaerkninger%2CSP_GEOMETRY&TYPENAME=spatialsuite%3ABoligprog_beregn_2021&REQUEST=GetFeature&RESULTTYPE=RESULTS&OUTPUTFORMAT=text%2Fxml%3B+subtype%3Dgml%2F3.1.1&VERSION=1.1.0&MAXFEATURES=1&SERVICE=WFS> ] [InvalidParameterValue: 
[Requested property: Sm�_boliger is not available for spatialsuite:Boligprog_beregn_2021. The possible propertyName values are: 
[MI_STYLE, ID, Kommuneplanramme, Lokalplan, Vedtaget_LP, LP_u_udarb, Skole, Stat, Areal_ha, Komm, Priv, Fam_boliger, Små_boliger, FB_2021_22, SB_2021_22, FB_2023_25, SB_2023_25, FB_2026_31, SB_2026_31, FB_Senere, SB_Senere, Almene_Fam, Almene_S, Lokalsamfund, Kategori_tal, Kategori_tekst, Kategori_til_kort, Kat_til_kort_nr, Oprettet_af, Oprettet_dato, Rettet_af, Rettet_dato, mi_prinx, Bemaerkninger, SP_GEOMETRY]]]"
```

TLDR: The Get-URL Changes a property name from `Små_boliger` to `Sm%EF%BF%BD_boliger` and will not return features.

Can I do anything to fix this? Or is changing the property name on the external service the only way?

**External wfs service:**

https://webkort.aarhuskommune.dk/wfs/spatialsuite/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities

**Log from the error:**

```
2021-09-24 09:58:20,327 TRACE [org.geotools.data.wfs.internal] - Creating GetFeature request parameters for {http://wfs.spatialserver.spatialsuite.com}Boligprog_beregn_2021
2021-09-24 09:58:20,327 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.wfs.internal] - Supported filter: Filter.INCLUDE. Unsupported filter: Filter.INCLUDE
2021-09-24 09:58:20,327 TRACE [org.geotools.data.wfs.internal] - Looking operation URI for GET_FEATURE/GET
2021-09-24 09:58:20,327 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.wfs.internal] - Returning operation URI for GET_FEATURE/GET: https://webkort.aarhuskommune.dk:443/wfs/spatialsuite/wfs
2021-09-24 09:58:20,327 TRACE [org.geotools.data.wfs.internal] - Built GET request for GET_FEATURE: https://webkort.aarhuskommune.dk:443/wfs/spatialsuite/wfs?PROPERTYNAME=MI_STYLE%2CID%2CKommuneplanramme%2CLokalplan%2CVedtaget_LP%2CLP_u_udarb%2CSkole%2CStat%2CAreal_ha%2CKomm%2CPriv%2CFam_boliger%2CSm%EF%BF%BD_boliger%2CFB_2021_22%2CSB_2021_22%2CFB_2023_25%2CSB_2023_25%2CFB_2026_31%2CSB_2026_31%2CFB_Senere%2CSB_Senere%2CAlmene_Fam%2CAlmene_S%2CLokalsamfund%2CKategori_tal%2CKategori_tekst%2CKategori_til_kort%2CKat_til_kort_nr%2COprettet_af%2COprettet_dato%2CRettet_af%2CRettet_dato%2Cmi_prinx%2CBemaerkninger%2CSP_GEOMETRY&TYPENAME=spatialsuite%3ABoligprog_beregn_2021&REQUEST=GetFeature&RESULTTYPE=RESULTS&OUTPUTFORMAT=text%2Fxml%3B+subtype%3Dgml%2F3.1.1&VERSION=1.1.0&MAXFEATURES=1&SERVICE=WFS
2021-09-24 09:58:20,327 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.ows] - FinalURL:https://webkort.aarhuskommune.dk:443/wfs/spatialsuite/wfs?PROPERTYNAME=MI_STYLE%2CID%2CKommuneplanramme%2CLokalplan%2CVedtaget_LP%2CLP_u_udarb%2CSkole%2CStat%2CAreal_ha%2CKomm%2CPriv%2CFam_boliger%2CSm%EF%BF%BD_boliger%2CFB_2021_22%2CSB_2021_22%2CFB_2023_25%2CSB_2023_25%2CFB_2026_31%2CSB_2026_31%2CFB_Senere%2CSB_Senere%2CAlmene_Fam%2CAlmene_S%2CLokalsamfund%2CKategori_tal%2CKategori_tekst%2CKategori_til_kort%2CKat_til_kort_nr%2COprettet_af%2COprettet_dato%2CRettet_af%2CRettet_dato%2Cmi_prinx%2CBemaerkninger%2CSP_GEOMETRY&TYPENAME=spatialsuite%3ABoligprog_beregn_2021&REQUEST=GetFeature&RESULTTYPE=RESULTS&OUTPUTFORMAT=text%2Fxml%3B+subtype%3Dgml%2F3.1.1&VERSION=1.1.0&MAXFEATURES=1&SERVICE=WFS
2021-09-24 09:58:20,449 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.wfs.internal] - Response head:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows https://webkort.aarhuskommune.dk:443/wfs/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue">
    <ows:ExceptionText>Requested property: Sm?_boliger is not available for spatialsuite:Boligprog_beregn_2021.  The possible propertyName values are: [MI_STYLE, ID, Kommuneplanramme, Lokalplan, Vedtaget_LP, LP_u_udarb, Skole, Stat, Areal_ha, Komm, Priv, Fam_boliger, Små_boliger, FB_2021_22, SB_2021_22, FB_2023_25, SB_2023_25, FB_2026_31, SB_2026_31, FB_Senere, SB_Senere, Almene_Fam, Almene_S, Lokalsamfund, Kategori_tal, Kategori_tekst, Kategori_til_kort, Kat_til_kort_nr, Oprettet_af, Oprettet_dato, Rettet_af, Rettet_dato, mi_prinx, Bemaerkninger, SP_GEOMETRY]</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

2021-09-24 09:58:20,464 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - schemaLocation found: http://www.opengis.net/ows https://webkort.aarhuskommune.dk:443/wfs/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd
2021-09-24 09:58:20,464 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/ows: https://webkort.aarhuskommune.dk:443/wfs/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd ==> jar:file:/C:/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-ows-23.1.jar!/org/geotools/xsd/ows/owsExceptionReport.xsd
2021-09-24 09:58:20,464 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - schema specified by parser configuration not found, supplementing...
```

**Picture of when the error occurs**

[image: Selecting polygon which returns error]

Comment: Hmm - it should be converted to `Sm%C3%A5_boliger`

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: can you add a link to the external service, so we can test against it

Comment: I added the link, though I am worried it might only open nationally.

Comment: It all seems to work for me (2.19.2) - what do you do when you "When I click an element to load features"?

Comment: I get the error If click a polygon in e.g. the Layer Preview of GeoServer or in QGIS to get feature info.

Comment: Is your geoserver running with utf-8 encoding? (startup java option `ENCODING="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"`)

Comment: Java isn't my strong side. How to I check/edit that?